# Gradient of n colors ranging from color 1 and color 2

Tags: r, gradient

I often work with `ggplot2` that makes gradients nice ([click here for an example](http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggtutorial-day-5-gradient-colors-and-brewer-palettes/)).  I have a need to work in base and I think `scales` can be used there to create color gradients as well but I'm severely off the mark on how.  The basic goal is generate a palette of n colors that ranges from x color to y color.  The solution needs to work in base though.  This was a starting point but there's no place to input an n.

```
 scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("red", "blue"))
```

I am well aware of:

```
brewer.pal(8, "Spectral")
```

from `RColorBrewer`.  I'm looking more for the approach similar to how `ggplot2` handles gradients that says I have these two colors and I want 15 colors along the way.  How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need the **scales** package; the latest **ggplot2** versions depend on this for the underlying code. I.e. you don't need **ggplot2** to use scales, you just need the **scales** package. No idea how the functions in **scales** works though :-)

Comment: Off-topic since you requested `base` specifically, but I find [`colourvalues`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/colourvalues) ([also on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colourvalues/index.html)) particularly convenient for mapping values to a gradient. It's also pretty lightweight (depends on `Rcpp`).

Comment: @MichaelChirico Not off topic, what I meant was that I needed to use base plotting because of the package I was using was written in base (I think wordcloud) rather than grid.  Maybe post as an answer?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

`colorRampPalette` could be your friend here:

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "white"))
colfunc(10)
# [1] "#000000" "#1C1C1C" "#383838" "#555555" "#717171" "#8D8D8D" "#AAAAAA"
# [8] "#C6C6C6" "#E2E2E2" "#FFFFFF"
```

And just to show it works:

```
plot(rep(1,10),col=colfunc(10),pch=19,cex=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if you're particularly enamoured with a pre-existing palette, e.g. `brewer.pal(8, "Spectral")`, you can give the resulting vector of colours to `colorRampPalette` to generate more colours along that ramp. For example: `colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Spectral"))`.

Comment: What about the color with the diagonoal lines or shapes in the block ? @thelatemail

Comment: If you would like to call this all in one line without having to assign `colfunc` then just do this: `colorRampPalette(c("black", "white"))(10)`

Answer (score 69):

Just to expand on the previous answer `colorRampPalette`can handle more than two colors.

So for a more expanded "heat map" type look you can....

```
colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","springgreen","royalblue"))
plot(rep(1,50),col=(colfunc(50)), pch=19,cex=2)
```

The resulting image:

[image]

Comment: can I also specify the diagonal lines or shapes in the color ? @jsol

Comment: I like this palette but there is way too much green and very little yellow. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Adding for anyone else who was not expecting to see an option like "springgreen" or "royalblue". All colors available to use can be returned as a list by running: colors().

Answer (score 24):

Try the following:

```
color.gradient <- function(x, colors=c("red","yellow","green"), colsteps=100) {
  return( colorRampPalette(colors) (colsteps) [ findInterval(x, seq(min(x),max(x), length.out=colsteps)) ] )
}
x <- c((1:100)^2, (100:1)^2)
plot(x,col=color.gradient(x), pch=19,cex=2)
```

[image: Colored plot using color.gradient]

**Edit**
Let me try to explain why I think this function is superior to the other suggested solutions.

Let's apply the function suggested by jsol for the exponential data I used for my plot. I try two variations using `range` and `length` in the call to `colfunc`.
Result: It simply does not work as intended.

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","springgreen","royalblue"))
x <- c((1:100)^2, (100:1)^2)
plot(x, col=colfunc(range(x)), pch=19,cex=2)
plot(x, col=colfunc(length(x)), pch=19,cex=2)
```

[image: Colored plot using confunc]

Comment: this function should be add as a default in R base!

Answer (score 8):

The above answer is useful but in graphs, it is difficult to distinguish between darker gradients of black. One alternative I found is to use gradients of gray colors as follows

```
palette(gray.colors(10, 0.9, 0.4))
plot(rep(1,10),col=1:10,pch=19,cex=3))
```

More info on gray scale [here.](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/gray.colors.html)

**Added**

When I used the code above for different colours like blue and black, the gradients were not that clear. 
`heat.colors()` seems more useful.

[This document](http://web.archive.org/web/20141111182737/http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jkim/Rcolorstyle.pdf) has more detailed information and options. [pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20141111182737/http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jkim/Rcolorstyle.pdf)

Comment: I think this answer is superior for black to white but is not generalizable to colors.  Thank you for adding this valuable information. +1

Comment: Added a link which provides better options for color gradients and hues which work in both color and B&W.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I might be having a saved copy of the file but not the updated link. Not sure where to upload it though.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte - http://web.archive.org/web/20141111182737/http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jkim/Rcolorstyle.pdf check archive.org first always.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach (not necessarily better than the previous answers!) is to use the `viridis` package. As explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html), it allows for a variety of color gradients that are based on more than two colors.

The package is pretty easy to use - you just need to replace the `ggplot2` scale fill function (e.g., `scale_fill_gradient(low = "skyblue", high = "dodgerblue4")`) with the equivalent `viridis` function.

So, change the code for this plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt*1000, mpg)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = hp)) +
  xlab("Weight (pounds)") + ylab("Miles per gallon (MPG)") + labs(color='Horse power') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1000, 6000), 
                     breaks = c(seq(1000,6000,1000)), 
                     labels = c("1,000", "2,000", "3,000", "4,000", "5,000", "6,000")) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "skyblue", high = "dodgerblue4") +
  theme_classic()
```

Which produces:

[image]

To this, which uses `viridis`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt*1000, mpg)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, aes(colour = factor(cyl))) +
  xlab("Weight (pounds)") + ylab("Miles per gallon (MPG)") + labs(color='Number\nof cylinders') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1000, 6000), 
                     breaks = c(seq(1000,6000,1000)), 
                     labels = c("1,000", "2,000", "3,000", "4,000", "5,000", "6,000")) + 
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme_classic()
```

The only difference is in the second to last line: `scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)`.

This is the plot that is produced using `viridis`:

[image]

Hoping someone finds this useful, as its the solution I ended up using after coming to this question.