# Adding a color key to contour plots in R

Tags: r, colors, key

I want to create a contour plot that has a color key next to it.

I would make the contour plot like this:

```
data(volcano)
image(volcano)
contour(volcano, add = TRUE)
```

However, `image()` does not support a legend as far as I know. I saw that there is also a `contourplot()` function in the `lattice` package, however, I cannot figure it out how to overlay
the map with the contour lines when using `levelplot(volcano)` and `contourplot(volcano)`

Ideally I want my plot to look like this but with a color key:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure someone has a `ggplot` solution to this, but this was also addressed in this question previously - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355176/gradient-legend-in-base

Comment: 3rd example from the bottom:   http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_contour.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Hm, I wanted to avoid using ggplot2, I can't help it, but I don't like the look of the ggplot2 graphics. But if there is no other way I might have to do it this way

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `image.plot` from the `fields` package. This creates a legend by default.

```
library(fields)
image.plot(volcano)
contour(volcano, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, this was something I was looking for!

Comment: Magic! Nice answer - will have to remember this one!