# How to get R plot to plot variable on heat.color scale

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting data in R. I'm running the following two commands:

```
plot(x = df$Latitude, df$Longitude, col = heat.colors(nrow(df)), type = "p")

plot(x = df$Latitude, df$Longitude, col = df$feature, type = "p")
```

The first line plots the points along a color gradient (points with higher values are red, points with lower values are yellow) and the second line plots data with color dictated by the int values given by `features`.

However, I want to combine both such that I'm plotting points with colors on a scale using the numeric values from `feature`. In some sense, I want to pass two arguments to `col`. How can I do this?

Comment: look at `ggplot2` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# some data
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)

# Create some breaks and use colorRampPalette to transform the breaks into a color code
gr <- .bincode(x, seq(min(x), max(x), len=length(x)), include.lowest = T)
col <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "blue"))(length(x))[gr]

# the plot:
plot(x, pch=16, col=col)
```

[image]

For a legend see solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355176/gradient-legend-in-base) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314658/colorbar-from-custom-colorramppalette)