# Dynamic colouring in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have the following R code that I am using to plot a set of time series, which are normalised `[0,1]`. I want each of the lines to have a color intensity such that all values `<= 0.5` have shades of blue and `> 0.5` have shades of orange/yellow. This is what I have right now:

```
data <- SOME_DATA

for(i in 1:length(data)){
  y <- data[[paste("I",i,sep = "")]]
  x <- 1:length(y)
  lo <- loess(y~x)
  ylim <- range(seq(-1,1,by=0.5))
  if(i==1){
    plot(x,y,ylim = ylim,main = "Some title",col = ifelse(y[1] < 0,'red','green'),ylab = "intensity",xlab = "time steps")
  }
  lines(predict(lo),lwd=2,ylim = ylim,col = ifelse(y[1] < 0,rgb(1,0,0,0.2),rgb(0,1,0,0.2)))
}
```

How can I go about achieving what I described above?

Thanks

Comment: You are just using base r functionality. No need for `plotly` in this example. I gave you an answer below. I hope this helps. Otherweise you have to provide more specific example.data so that we can run your code.

Comment: Edited - sorry it seems like I was using it for some other code below in the script..

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656396/993718) solution you can do the following:

```
data <- data.frame(x= runif(100), y = runif(100))
color.gradient <- function(x, colors=c("blue","white","red"), colsteps=100) {
  return( colorRampPalette(colors) (colsteps) [ findInterval(x, seq(min(x),max(x), length.out=colsteps)) ] )
}
plot(data$x, data$y, col= color.gradient(data$x))
```

[image: R plot preview]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more configurable image may be possible with ggplot. Using data and color.gradient from @jakobr :

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+ geom_point(col=color.gradient(data$x))+ theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a very good practice. If you are using ggplot2 then you should definitely make use of `ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = x)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red")`!