# Automatically detect correct number of colorRampPalette values needed

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353213/gradient-of-n-colors-ranging-from-color-1-and-color-2).

If I create a gradient using `colorRampPalette`, is there a way to have `ggplot2` automatically detect the number of colours it will need from this gradient?

In the example below, I have to specify 3 colours will be needed for the 3 `cyl` values. This requires me knowing ahead of time that I'll need this many. I'd like to not have to specify it and have `ggplot` detect the number it will need automatically.

```
myColRamp <- colorRampPalette(c('#a0e2f2', '#27bce1'))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = myColRamp(3)) # How to avoid having to specify 3?
```

I'm also open to options that don't use colorRampPalette but achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here. One which requires a little customisation. One which has more code but requires no customisation.

**Option 1 -** Determine number of unique factors from your specific variable

Simply use the `length` and `unique` functions to work out how many factors are in `cyl`.

```
values = myColRamp(length(unique(mtcars$cyl))
```

**Option 2 -** Build the plot, and see how many colours it used

If you don't want to specify the name of the variable, and want something more general, we can build the plot, and see how many colours ggplot used, then build it again.

To do this, we also have to save our plot as an object, let's call that plot object `p`.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl))) +
     geom_point(size = 3)
     #Notice I haven't set the colour option this time


p_built <- ggplot_build(p) #This builds the plot and saves the data based on
                           #the plot, so x data is called 'x', y is called 'y',
                           #and importantly in this case, colour is called the
                           #generic 'colour'.

#Now we can fish out that data and check how many colour levels were used
num_colours <- length(unique(p_built$data[[1]]$colour))

#Now we know how many colours were used, we can add the colour scale to our plot
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = myColRamp(num_colours))
```

Now either just call `p` or `print(p)` depending on your use to view it.

Comment: While these work, they're not what I'd consider 'automatic' in the sense that the default colour scheme will 'automatically' select the correct number of colours (i.e. number of factors). Here there are intermediate steps and objects stored, which isn't quite what I was hoping for.

Comment: In the first option I present there's no intermediate steps or objects stored. The issue is when replicating, it would need updating when the variable name changed.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the storage. However, I often have a long sequence of data manipulations piped together and finally piped into the ggplot function. This means I can't call `unique(mtcars$cyl)`, as the actual dataset plotted isn't stored anywhere in the same format. I was hoping there would be a way to reference the data ingested (e.g. with a `.` or something). I _could_ store it, then plot it and use your Option 1, but this is not what I'm after with this question. Perhaps it's not possible.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately I don't know that there is a way to do that precisely. There might be another way around the problem though. Did you want to add an extended version of the problem including some of these piping situations and we might be able to come up with a better work-around?