# Save color gradient values in a R dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big dataframe with a p-values column that loosk like the snippet below

```
myPvalues<-data.frame(pvalues=c(0.00431279265850473,NA,0.00067818958352233,NA,NA,NA,0.00826354450511943,0.00605467431746949,0.00518801869607421,0.00896893103806155))
```

I would like to map those values to colors, by using a heat map either already defined or to be created. I  understand how to make a plot which colors my data in the proper way, but I don't know how I can add a column to my data frame that save those values for the colors, such that the data frame now has also a column like

```
myPvalues$Colors<-c("#75F4A1","#FFFFFFFF","#547CB8","#FFFFFFFF","#FFFFFFFF","#FFFFFFFF","#F9A13A","#D6F667","#92FC79","#F58046")
```

where "white" is for NA values, and the other values are codes for colors (here, I put arbitrary codes but they would need to be colors from a color gradient with extremes defined by min(myPvalues$pvalues) and max(myPvalues$pvalues).

I have been looking around but found no solution that quite addresses this problem. Would anybody give me a pointer?

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353213/gradient-of-n-colors-ranging-from-color-1-and-color-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define your gradient colors. I selected red and green and at random.

```
library(tidyverse)

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c('red', 'green'))
```

Then you need to calculate where your current colors rank. Important to note that `colorRampPalette()` requires an integer input, so the difference in colors *between* values won't always look right.

```
pvalue_forColors <- myPvalues %>%
  drop_na(pvalues) %>% 
  arrange(pvalues) %>%
  mutate(rank = row_number())

myPvalues <- left_join(myPvalues, pvalue_forColors, by = 'pvalues')
```

Generate your gradient

```
the_colors <- tibble(rank = 1:max(myPvalues$rank, na.rm = T), color_code = colfunc(max(myPvalues$rank, na.rm = T)))
```

Final column called `color_code` with a gradient and white for missing values.

```
myPvalues %>%
  left_join(the_colors, by = 'rank') %>%
  mutate(color_code = if_else(is.na(pvalues), '#FFFFFFFF', color_code))
```

Comment: Harrison: thanks a lot, this does what I want; I could adapt it to my case (I use it to set the background color of several plots to be composed by ggarrange). Perhaps  in the last code snipped in 'myPvalues%>%' you meant 'myPvalues<-myPvalues%>%'. Many thanks

Comment: using `myPvalues <- myPvalues %>%` as opposed to just `myPvalues %>%` definitely works to assign it back to the same object name. I just didn't bother assigning so you could see the output. If the solution works for you, feel free to Accept the answer.